# Print() vs Write() method of System.out

Tags: java, printstream

The Javadoc for [PrintStream#print(char)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print(char)) states

> Prints a character. The character is translated into one or more bytes
>   according to the platform's default character encoding, and these
>   bytes are written in exactly the manner of the write(int) method.

So this means that following code should print 2 **'a'** however prints one **'a'** not two.

```
System.out.print('a');
System.out.write('a');
```

Can some one help me understand this behaviour

Comment: This will print two `a`s. Are you saying that in your case it is printing only one `a`?

Comment: Try flushing...

Comment: @VHS Yes..it is printing 1 a .. :(

Comment: I don't understand the negative vote here. The question is well formed and within the scope of SO

Comment: @4castle, your link points to PrintWriter class, not PrinttStream. [Here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/io/PrintStream.java#PrintStream.print%28char%29) is the correct link. If you see this code, you will see that there is a different implementation of print from that of write. It is a design decision.

Comment: @MangatRaiModi, I didn't downvote it. But I think someone downvoted it because the OP mentioned in a comment that there is some contradiction in the documentation of these two methods and yet he didn't clarify what contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

As per the [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#write(int)) of `PrintStream#write`

> Writes the specified byte to this stream. If the byte is a newline and
>   automatic flushing is enabled then the flush method will be invoked.

So just call `flush`.

Call `System.out.flush();` after `System.out.write('a');`.

**Alternately**,

As the docs suggest, set the output stream to `autoflushable` and then write a new line char at the end of your program. In fact the PrintStream object `System.out` is already set to autoflushable if you look at the source code [System class](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/System.java#System.0out). So really, all you need to do is just print a new line character in the end. No need to call flush.

```
System.out.print('a');
System.out.write('a');
System.out.write('\n');
```

Comment: Yes but if i go by the docs of print() char then statement is contradicting.

Comment: @ShowStopper There is no 'link of `char()`' in your question.

Comment: Oh you meant print(char). I had already checked that link. it doesn't state that it requires automatic flushing set to true.

Comment: @ShowStopper Nor is `'a'` a newline. There is no contradiction. Your point remains obscure.

Comment: Thanks @EJP. ShowStopper, if you have reservations against using flush, you can set the output stream to autoflush and then just print a new line in the end. Let me edit my answer to show it.

Comment: Why does the `print(char)` flush, but `write(int)` doesn't?

Comment: @4castle, I would say that's by class design. The java docs clearly say flush is required for write. But they don't say that for print.